# What is a word to describe when someone is upset that someone else thinks little of themself?

Tags: dialogue, word-choice

I'm writing a story and the characters have just got to their love confession and I'm trying to think of a specific word to capture their feeling, but I can't remember it.

Character A: "They're not my type. You are."
Character B: "Me?"
Character A gives B an [insulted] look, "Yes, you."

[Insulted] is where I'm trying to fit the word in.

It's driving me bonkers, because I'm positive there's a word for the feeling of basically being insulted on another's behalf. I've already looked up affronted and indignified, but neither I believe is the correct word.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ***disbelief***? ***chagrin***?

Comment: I suggest the question be sent back to Writers. The context suggests picking a rather more generic word to describe the feelings of character A than a word specialised to B having a particular psychological state.

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't think of anything, imagine their expression and describe that (maybe their eyebrows are doing something, or their eyes are bright or sad or their mouth is in a line, ect.)
This might not be helpful, but:
Sympathetic
Offended
Pained
Whistful
Indignant is a good one though (you could say "Character A gave B a look, indignant on his/her behalf. 'Yes, you.'")

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the last bit. That is actually a great way to put it. 